# how to replace a string with matching words in array at index position

Tags: javascript

How to add a sentence to the array and replace the words matching to it.

Example, for the given input:

```
let arrayWords = ["Hellow", "World", "is", "a", "beautiful" , "Hellow", "Princes", "is", "smart", "Hellow", "Maria"];
let sentence = "Hellow Princes is smart";
```

Required output:

```
arrayWords = ["Hellow", "World", "is", "a", "beautiful", "Hellow Princes is smart", "Hellow", "Maria"]
```

Here is the code:

```
let temp =sentence.split(' ');
if (temp.length > 1) {
  arrayWords.splice(arrayWords.indexOf(temp[0]),temp.length,sentence);
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code you tried?  How do you determine where the string is inserted in the array? Why isn't the string `is` taken out?

Comment: @SvenWritesCode actual code is in angularjs1, i have just tried to convert it into javascript

Comment: @SvenWritesCode while performing above it replaces the starting words from array

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit tricky, but try this:

**! Assumption**: Each word in `sentence` is in same exact sequence somewhere in the `arrayWords`.

```js
let arrayWords = ["Hellow", "World", "is", "a", "beautiful" , "Hellow", "Princes", "is", "smart", "Hellow", "Maria"]
let sentence= "Hellow Princes is smart"

let arraySentence = arrayWords.join(' ');

let newArray = arraySentence.replace(sentence, sentence.replace(/\s/g, '#')).split(' ').map(item => item.replace(/#/g, ' '));

console.log(newArray);
```

I've done the following steps:

1. Convert array into `sentence` separated by spaces.
2. Replace the substring in `arraySentence` by your `sentence`, but
   spaces here are converted to `#`. (This is needed so that we can differentiate between spaces for other words and spaces within this `sentence` substring. See Step 4)
3. Split `arraySentence` by spaces to form an array once more.
4. Replace the `#` with space again with `filter`.

**EDIT :** Creating function for handling multiple sentences changes.

```js
function preserveSpaces(text) {
   return text.replace(/\s/g, '#');
}
function revertToSpaces(text) {
   return text.replace(/#/g, ' ');
}

function reduceArray(arrayWords, sentence) {
  let arraySentence = arrayWords.map(preserveSpaces).join(' ');
  return arraySentence.replace(sentence, preserveSpaces(sentence)).split(' ').map(revertToSpaces);
}


let arrayWords = ["Hellow", "World", "is", "a", "beautiful" , "Hellow", "Princes", "is", "smart", "Hellow", "Maria"]


arrayWords = reduceArray(arrayWords, "Hellow Princes is smart");
console.log(arrayWords);

arrayWords = reduceArray(arrayWords, "Hellow Maria");
console.log(arrayWords);

arrayWords = reduceArray(arrayWords, "Hellow World is a beautiful");
console.log(arrayWords);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response with solution, but I dont want to create a new array, In example I have given a single sentence, but there can be n number of sentences and the words

Comment: Yeah, I think you can achieve that easily; 1. assign `newArray` to `arrayWords`. 2. make it a function that takes parameters as `(array, sentence)` which I believe you can implement easily once you get down to it. Happy Coding!

Comment: what will happen when the second sentence `Hellow Maria` needs to replace, it should not make problem to `Hellow Princes is smart`

Comment: I have tried the given code but it gives undefined output

Comment: Check the Edit for multiple sentences.

Comment: thanks, code words as is, but I don't want to use regex, so have used different approach

Answer (score 0):

@n4m31ess_c0d3r thanks for your response, I got some clue from that, Below is the code which I have used to resolve the problem; It may not be the best way, I am still working on it

```js
//Given array of words
let arrayWords = ["Hellow", "World", "is", "a", "beautiful", "Hellow", "Princes", "is", "smart", "Hellow", "Maria"];
//input sentence
let sentence = "Hellow Princes is smart";


let tmpWords = sentence.split(' ');
let tempIndexes = [];

//finding all index position for first word in sentence
for (let i = 0; i < arrayWords.length; i++) {
    if (arrayWords[i] === tmpWords[0]) {
        tempIndexes.push(i);
    }
}

//checking the sequence words by calculating its index value
var matchindex = -1;
for (var x = 0; x < tempIndexes.length; x++) {
    var matchFound = true;
    for (var y = 0; y < tmpWords.length; y++) {
        if (arrayWords[tempIndexes[x] + y] != tmpWords[y]) {
            matchFound = false;
        }
    }
    if (matchFound) {
        matchindex = x;
        break;
    }
}
arrayWords.splice([tempIndexes[matchindex]], tmpWords.length, sentence);
console.log(arrayWords);
```